# Creating new columns that go from 0 to the value in the variable of a table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

**Reproducible tibble:** I have a database similar to the one shown below. The difference being that the database I'm working with is much bigger.

```
general_tibble <- tibble(gender = c("female", "female", "male"),
                             age = c(18, 19,18),
                             age_partner = c(22,20,17),
                             max_age = c(60, 60, 65), 
                             nrs =c(42,41,47))
```

`general_tibble` results in :

```
  gender age age_partner max_age nrs
1 female  18          22      60  42
2 female  19          20      60  41
3   male  18          17      65  47
```

**Question:** 
How do I create a new table from a previous table, that takes the value of `nrs`, and creates a column variable, called  `n`,  that goes from 0 to the value in `nrs`?

To illustrate further, in row 1 of `general_tibble` the column `nrs` is equal to 42 so the column would go from 0 to 42, in row 2 `nrs`is equal to 41 so the column would go from 0 to 41, and the same for row 3.

I am currently using the code below.  It works, but when `general_tibble` is too big, the code performs really slow.

```
general_list <- list()

for(i in 1:NROW(general_tibble)){
  general_list[[i]] <- data.frame(general_tibble[i, ], 
                             n = 0:general_tibble[[i, "nrs"]])
}
```

Then I `bind_rows()` `general_list` to obtain  `general_binded`

```
general_binded <- bind_rows(general_list)
```

`general_binded[c(1:5, 38:42),]` results in :

```
   gender age age_partner max_age nrs  n
1  female  18          22      60  42  0
2  female  18          22      60  42  1
3  female  18          22      60  42  2
4  female  18          22      60  42  3
5  female  18          22      60  42  4
38 female  18          22      60  42 37
39 female  18          22      60  42 38
40 female  18          22      60  42 39
41 female  18          22      60  42 40
42 female  18          22      60  42 41
```

**PS:** In the for loop I use `data.frame()` instead of `tibble()` because i want to recycle the rows. If you have some sort of advice involving tibbles or dataframes, ill gladly take it.

Comment: Seems related [Faster equivalent to group_by %>% expand in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103276/faster-equivalent-to-group-by-expand-in-r)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One nice thing about using `data.table` vs `tidyverse` is that you don't need to think of operations in terms of whether what you're doing is a `mutate`, `expand`, or `summarize`. You can just put what you want in the `j` part of `df[i, j, k]` and however many rows that resolves to, that's what you get.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(general_tibble)

general_tibble[, .(n = seq(0, nrs))
               , by = names(general_tibble)]


#      gender age age_partner max_age nrs  n
#   1: female  18          22      60  42  0
#   2: female  18          22      60  42  1
#   3: female  18          22      60  42  2
#   4: female  18          22      60  42  3
#   5: female  18          22      60  42  4
#  ---                                      
# 129:   male  18          17      65  47 43
# 130:   male  18          17      65  47 44
# 131:   male  18          17      65  47 45
# 132:   male  18          17      65  47 46
# 133:   male  18          17      65  47 47
```

Answer (score 5):

Easiest approach towards this would be expanding the `general_tibble` on `nrs` column using `tidyr::expand()` function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

general_tibble %>% 
        group_by_all()%>% 
        expand(n = 0:nrs)

#> # A tibble: 133 x 6
#> # Groups:   gender, age, age_partner, max_age, nrs [3]
#>    gender   age age_partner max_age   nrs     n
#>    <chr>  <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 female    18          22      60    42     0
#>  2 female    18          22      60    42     1
#>  3 female    18          22      60    42     2
#>  4 female    18          22      60    42     3
#>  5 female    18          22      60    42     4
#>  6 female    18          22      60    42     5
#>  7 female    18          22      60    42     6
#>  8 female    18          22      60    42     7
#>  9 female    18          22      60    42     8
#> 10 female    18          22      60    42     9
#> # ... with 123 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

---

Just another idea using only *`base R`* functions:

```r
expanded_vars <- do.call(rbind,lapply(general_tibble$nrs, 
                                              function(x) expand.grid(x, 0:x)))
names(expanded_vars) <- c("nrs", "n")

merge(y = expanded_vars, x = general_tibble, by = "nrs", all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, the `group_by_all() %>% expand()` worked great. However, I'm now facing the problem that it takes around 15 minutes to expand a tibble of about 600,000 rows. What do you suggest?

Comment: @DennisAguilar give Toucan's data.table solution a shot, since data.table is generally faster. Another idea at the moment is splitting after grouping, expanding and then rowbinding (not sure if that would help tho).

Answer (score 2):

We may use `uncount`

```
library(tidyverse)
general_tibble %>% 
   mutate(grp = row_number(), nrsN = nrs + 1) %>% 
   uncount(nrsN) %>%
   group_by(grp) %>% 
   mutate(n = row_number() - 1) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 133 x 6
#   gender   age age_partner max_age   nrs     n
#   <chr>  <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 female    18          22      60    42     0
# 2 female    18          22      60    42     1
# 3 female    18          22      60    42     2
# 4 female    18          22      60    42     3
# 5 female    18          22      60    42     4
# 6 female    18          22      60    42     5
# 7 female    18          22      60    42     6
# 8 female    18          22      60    42     7
# 9 female    18          22      60    42     8
#10 female    18          22      60    42     9
# … with 123 more rows
```

---

Another option is `unnest`

```
general_tibble %>% 
   mutate(n = map(nrs+1, ~  seq(.x) - 1)) %>%
   unnest
```

Answer (score 1):

One way with base R (minus the `tibble` package).

First, split by the `nrs` group. Second, expand the rows of each dataframe by the `nrs` value. Third, create an `id` column that represents 0:whatever number of rows. Fourth, bring it back to a `tibble`:

```r
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(
  gender      = c("female", "female", "male"),
  age         = c(18, 19, 18),
  age_partner = c(22, 20, 17),
  max_age     = c(60, 60, 65), 
  nrs         = c(42, 41, 47)
  )

nrs_split <- split(df, df$nrs)
df_list <- lapply(nrs_split, function(i) i[rep(seq_len(nrow(i)), each=i$nrs + 1), ])
df_renum <- lapply(df_list, function(i) {i$id <- 0:rle(i$nrs)$values; return(i)})
df <- do.call("rbind", df_renum)
df
#> # A tibble: 133 x 6
#>    gender   age age_partner max_age   nrs    id
#>  * <chr>  <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 female    19          20      60    41     0
#>  2 female    19          20      60    41     1
#>  3 female    19          20      60    41     2
#>  4 female    19          20      60    41     3
#>  5 female    19          20      60    41     4
#>  6 female    19          20      60    41     5
#>  7 female    19          20      60    41     6
#>  8 female    19          20      60    41     7
#>  9 female    19          20      60    41     8
#> 10 female    19          20      60    41     9
#> # … with 123 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can also do:

```
general_tibble %>%
 group_by(rowid = row_number()) %>%
 mutate(n = nrs) %>%
 complete(n = seq(0, n, 1)) %>%
 fill(everything(), .direction = "up") %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rowid)

       n gender   age age_partner max_age   nrs
   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0 female    18          22      60    42
 2     1 female    18          22      60    42
 3     2 female    18          22      60    42
 4     3 female    18          22      60    42
 5     4 female    18          22      60    42
 6     5 female    18          22      60    42
 7     6 female    18          22      60    42
 8     7 female    18          22      60    42
 9     8 female    18          22      60    42
10     9 female    18          22      60    42
```